# Using Google Map to Select a location

Tags: google-maps

I want to get address info for the user when registering in my web site. I want to display a Google Map and let the user choose the country, then the city. When this happen, I will display the city in google map, let the user then choose the exact longitude and latitude by clicking on the map. I save that in my database.

Can I get some help, how can I start doing that?

Comment: i would start with here http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html

Comment: there's a complete and easy solution here: http://www.wimagguc.com/projects/jquery-latitude-longitude-picker-gmaps/

Answer (score 15):

Using the google maps v3 api to do this is pretty simple. You can use it directly. I wrote a jQuery wrapper to help a bit. Here is a blog post showing how to use the wrapper:

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/06/a-google-maps-version-3-jquery-plugin/

Hope this gets you started.

Bob

Comment: thanks a lot I think it's useful plugin and I'm studying it now

Comment: that requires GPS, it doesn't solve the question of how to let the user select the location from a map.